# Can the Shepherd druid's Spirit Totem feature be used in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape

The druid's [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) feature says, in part (PHB, p. 66-67):

> You can't cast spells. [...] You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source, and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.

The relevant part of the [Circle of the Shepherd druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleoftheShepherd)'s [Spirit Totem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#SpiritTotem-676) feature says (XGtE, p. 23):

> Starting at 2nd level, you gain the ability to call forth nature spirits and use them to influence the world around you. As a bonus action, you can magically summon an incorporeal spirit to a point you can see within 60 feet of you.

Can you use the **Spirit Totem** feature of the Circle of the Shepherd druid while you are in your Wild Shape form?

From what I can deduce, Spirit Totem would be available for a Druid to use in Wild Shape form because it is a class feature, not a spell (though it is magical).

I would appreciate any answers to support or contest this. If you or your table have play-tested this feature, even better!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, Spirit Totem can be used while in Wild Shape

While obviously exactly whether a feature is retained is reliant on DM judgement/approval, Spirit Totem is a feature with no physical requirements, so it should be usable in any form (humanoid, beast, or elemental).

(This is what you might call a plain-reading answer; there isn't really much to quote and/or point to that isn't already in the question.)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question and it's helpful you pointed out that there are no "physical requirements"  and also elemental forms. Had forgotten about that. :)